# Error al utilizar dos SUM en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, sum

Tengo este procedimiento almacenado que calcula el subtotal, iva y total, primeramente estaba solo un SUM y me traia varios registros con el Subtotal, IVA y Total, entonces puse un segundo SUM porque yo necesitaba sumar todos y que quedara un SUBTOTAL, IVA Y TOTAL, pero al agregarle el segundo SUM me salio el siguiente error **Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.**

```
SELECT SUM(SUM((precio*Monedas.tipoCambio)*(cantidad))) AS Subtotal, SUM(SUM(impuesto*cantidad*Monedas.tipoCambio)) AS IVA, SUM(SUM((descuento*Monedas.tipoCambio))) AS Descuento, SUM((((SUM(precio*Monedas.tipoCambio)*cantidad)-SUM(descuento*Monedas.tipoCambio))+SUM(impuesto*cantidad*Monedas.tipoCambio))) AS Total FROM detalleCotizacion
INNER JOIN Productos ON Productos.idProducto = detalleCotizacion.idProducto
INNER JOIN Monedas ON Monedas.codigoMoneda = Productos.codigoMoneda
WHERE idCotizacion=@idCotizacion
GROUP BY cantidad
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas un doble `SUM`, necesitas quitar el `GROUP BY`. Además, necesitas eliminar todas esos paréntesis adicionales y dar formato al código.

```
SELECT SUM( precio    * M.tipoCambio * cantidad)    AS Subtotal, 
       SUM( impuesto  * M.tipoCambio * cantidad)    AS IVA, 
       SUM( descuento * M.tipoCambio)               AS Descuento, 
       SUM( precio    * M.tipoCambio * cantidad)
        + SUM( impuesto  * M.tipoCambio * cantidad)
        - SUM( descuento * M.tipoCambio)            AS Total 
FROM detalleCotizacion AS C
INNER JOIN Productos   AS P ON P.idProducto   = C.idProducto
INNER JOIN Monedas     AS M ON M.codigoMoneda = P.codigoMoneda
WHERE C.idCotizacion = @idCotizacion
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias si me funciono, disculpa por el mal formato es que es mi primer programa que hago que no sea en la escuela que estudio

Comment: Si te acostumbras a dar un formato legible a tu código, verás que será más fácil corregirlo y darle mantenimiento.

Comment: En verdad que si esta muchisimo mas entendible, me ha pasado en otros procedimientos que cuando hacen mal un calculo prefiero borrarlo y hacerlo de nuevo por la dificultad por entenderlo al modificarlo